# Is it possible to add one table column name, in like query

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to write a query like this ?

```
SELECT *
FROM users u INNER JOIN items i
ON i.id = u.id
WHERE i.item_name LIKE '%u.name%'
```

give me any sample like query, which using another table column name

Comment: Yes, but it select all

Comment: you should mention that you have tried it and the results in your question. This will help anyone to understand what issue are you having and we would know that you actually tried to find the answer on your own :)

Comment: For what it's worth, the term for this is a "non-equijoin". All the databases I've worked with (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, Teradata) support them but they're generally rare. The more usual type is the "equijoin", which we see all the time (`JOIN items i ON i.id = u.id`). Like equijoins, non-equijoins can be inner, left, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query will need to look like this

```
SELECT *
FROM users u INNER JOIN items i
ON i.id = u.id
WHERE i.item_name LIKE CONCAT('%', u.name, '%');
```

on a side note this may be slow search because you are using LIKE with %some%. this caused a table scan each time. 
You may want to consider searching using [Full-Text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html) and with `MATCH()... AGAINST()` logic